# GIT Failed to create process

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, git, aws-codecommit

When trying to use git commands like git clone, git push, git pull I get this error message. But when I try to use git in the git hub repository, everything works normally, the error only occurs when trying to use these commands in git with an AWS repository, important to remember that I use the AWS Command Line Interface.

I already tried reinstalling, reinstalling git-remote-codecommit, but none of that works.
What was expected is an interaction to put the MFA, so I can execute the command, in this case git pull

Answer (score 0):

I fixed by uninstalling and then installing as as admin